# anchor build isn't working properly

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang

im trying to build my anchor program for a long time but it isn't working.

i tried to degrade solana-cli version to `1.10.0` and `1.9.0` and `1.10.29` but it didn't work.

[image: error]

Comment: Could you change out the error image for text instead? Google cannot index images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue when I brew installed rust. Install Rust using the normal way of you did that:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

Otherwise try making sure your `cargo build-bpf` works standalone. If it doesn't, reinstall Solana toolsuite CLI because it seems like something went wrong on your side

Comment: thank you so much. this worked. 

had to uninstall via brew and install via curl